# Remove email address from string

Tags: java, regex

How can I remove email address from a string? And all other digits and special characters?

Sample String can be

```
"Hello world my # is 123 mail me @ test@test.com"
```

Out put string should be

```
"Hello world my is mail me"
```

I googled this and found that I can use following regular expressions

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9\\.\\@_\\-~#]+"
```

but that example was more to check valid email ids not removing it. 
I am new to java!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by others, you could use regular expressions to clean up your String and replace unwanted part by an empty string `""`. To do so, have a look at the [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the `String` class and at the [`Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class for the syntax of regular expressions in Java.

Below, some code demonstrating one way to clean the provided sample String (maybe not the most elegant though):

```
String input = "Hello world my # is 123 mail me @ test@test.com";
String EMAIL_PATTERN = "([^.@\\s]+)(\\.[^.@\\s]+)*@([^.@\\s]+\\.)+([^.@\\s]+)";

String output = input.replaceAll(EMAIL_PATTERN, "") // Replace emails 
                                                    // by an empty string
        .replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "") // Replace all punctuation. One of
                                      // !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
        .replaceAll("\\d", "") // Replace any digit by an empty string
        .replaceAll("\\p{Blank}{2,}+", " "); // Replace any Blank (a  space or 
                                             // a tab) repeated more than once
                                             // by a single space.

System.out.println(output);
```

Running this code produces the following output:

```
Hello world my is mail me
```

If you need to remove more garbage (or less, like punctuation), well, you've got the principle. Adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: This is great, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for this. Just let it replace any regex matches by an empty string `""`. The regex you mentioned is however not very robust. A better one is this ([copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/1931322#1931322) and slightly changed for use in plain vanilla text):

```
string = string.replaceAll("([^.@\\s]+)(\\.[^.@\\s]+)*@([^.@\\s]+\\.)+([^.@\\s]+)", "");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that he doesn't just want to remove email addresses, he wants to remove *all* "special" characters (for some unknown definition of "special", but clearly including numbers, a hash mark, and an ampersand...).

Comment: Oh. For that just use `string = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}\\s]", "");` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Java regular expression [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class and its uses. There's a [useful tutorial here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/) which includes [replacement methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html).

An aside: [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is a particularly robust regexp to use for RFC822-compliant email addresses :-) You should be able to come up with something more concise for your needs! There's a discussion of email regexps and trade-offs [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: This one is unnecessarily overwhelming long and doesn't cover the upcoming ICANN decision to allow unicode characters (Arabic, Chinese, Hebrew, Japanese, Cyrillic, etc) in URL's and email addresses.

Comment: It was meant to be tongue-in-cheek and not particularly to be recommended. I will add a smiley.

Comment: And note the proviso re. RFC822

Comment: I know - I thought I'd written it originally and I hadn't :-(

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it looks like it's not just email addresses you're interested in removing, it's *all* non-alpha characters, so this is trivial:

```
str = str.replaceAll("([^.@\\s]+)(\\.[^.@\\s]+)*@([^.@\\s]+\\.)+([^.@\\s]+)", "")
         .replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha} ]", "")
         .replaceAll("[ ]{2,}+", " ");
```

See [the `Pattern` JavaDocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for information about what the special character class `\p{Alpha}` means...

Comment: You're right that the OP doesn't want to only remove the email but I don't think he wants to remove spaces :)

Comment: Fair point -- modified, and added a check for multiple spaces to collapse them into one, as per his example.

Comment: And finally used BalusC's code for email check, to make it all as per the OP's example.